# Wordpress expires session when refresh page

Tags: wordpress

I was working on WordPress and currently I met a problem with session. 
I used the theme Twentyfourteen. After I login, it shows admin page but when I refresh page, it shows the login again?

How to prevent this in WordPress?

Comment: can anyone help me please

Comment: change your theme in the admin panel. If that doesn't work, turn off all of your plugins. If that doesn't work, it isn't wordpress most likely.

Comment: I need to use this theme becuase my client need it. For turn off all plugins, I have done it already, but still the same. 
Anymore solution???

Comment: that wasn't a solution. that was a debugging approach. if you switch the theme do you continue to have problems?

Comment: Yes, when I switch the theme this problem is solve. So what can I do? I really need this theme for my client???

Comment: So, your problem is with a default them in WP. It is not clear what the interplay might be with your plugins. You will need to go through  and systematically isolate your problem. You should also go to the [WP support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Troubleshooting) and ask there.

Comment: thanks you for your answer